# How can I add a single line to a scatter plot in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

Consider the following MWE to draw a scatter plot using the python API to plotly:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs
import plotly.offline
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

data = list(range(10))
trace = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x=list(range(len(data))),
    y=data
)
plotly.offline.iplot([trace])
```

[image]

What if I now want to add a (say) horizontal line to this plot?
I went through the documentation, for example the section on [line and scatter](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/) and that on [line charts](https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/), but none of the examples seem to cover how to overlay different plots, or simply draw straight lines and similar shapes.

A naive approach to do this is to just add the line as a second scatter plot, like the following:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs
import plotly.offline
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

data = list(range(10))
trace = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x=list(range(len(data))),
    y=data
)
trace_line = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    x=list(range(len(data))),
    y=[4] * len(data),
    mode='lines'
)
plotly.offline.iplot([trace, trace_line])
```

[image]

This approach seems however to be suboptimal: aside for the verbosity required to add a single line, it also makes me manually "sample" the straight line, and it adds the line height to the tooltip on mouse hover.

Is there a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Could you not just add another data set that has all the same values and plot that?

Comment: @Jeeter sure you can, see my edit. I was hoping for a better approach than that. For example, using `cufflinks`+`pandas` one can add the `hline` and `vline` options to `iplot` to achieve this (see e.g. `In[43]` [here](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/)). Isn't there an equivalent way when using only `plotly`?

Comment: I actually don't have much experience with plotly, so I don't know. Hope you find your answer, though!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi from your question I can see that you need plotly shapes functionality and generate a horizontal line for the plot.

Please find below the code for doing the same graph you have shown in the question

**Code:**

```
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go


data = list(range(10))
trace = go.Scatter(
    x=list(range(len(data))),
    y=data
)
layout = {
    'shapes': [
        # Line Horizontal
        {
            'type': 'line',
            'x0': 0,
            'y0': 4,
            'x1': 10,
            'y1': 4,
            'line': {
                'color': 'rgb(50, 171, 96)',
                'width': 4
            },
        }
    ],
    'showlegend': True
}

fig = {
    'data': [trace],
    'layout': layout,
}


iplot(fig)
```

**Output:**

[image: plotly shapes]

**Additional reference:**

1. [plotly shapes examples](https://plot.ly/python/shapes/)
2. [plotly shapes reference](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-shapes)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks! By the way, why do you need to import `cufflinks`, `plotly.tools` and `download_plotlyjs` for this?

Comment: @glS I edited my code, those are brought when I copied from another cell, please refer to the updated code.

Comment: How can I add a label to the horizontal line? `name` doesn't appear to work

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could use the add_shape method, see the [doc](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/) here. If you add the following code, you could add the line same as y=4 as above.

```
fig.add_shape(type="line",
              x0=4, 
              y0=0, 
              x1=4, 
              y1=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the next line:

```
fig.add_hline(y=4, line_width=2, line_dash='dash')
```

Also checkout the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/) for further deep into the features that plotly recently has added.